# Selenium cant click button element

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

i am using selenium with python and i am trying to click a button but it doesn't seem to work.  Here's the html part:

```html
<div class="nmMym">
   <button class="sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    " type="button">
      <div class="                     Igw0E     IwRSH      eGOV_         _4EzTm                                                                                              qJPeX                ">
         <div class="_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm KV-D4          uL8Hv         ">Annehmen</div>
      </div>
   </button>
</div>
```

I already tried clicking the button by xpath and class, nothing worked. It also doesnt even give me an error.
I'm happy about every answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find you button by its text:
**Try 1:**

```
your_button= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div/div[contains(text(), 'Annehmen')]")
```

Or, another way:
**Try 2:**

```
your_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button/div/div[contains(@class,'_7UhW9   xLCgt       qyrsm KV-D4          uL8Hv         ')]")
```

Try to omit `//button/div/` by using just:
**Try 3**

```
your_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Annehmen')]")
```

**Try 4:**
Another option:

```
your_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[contains(@class,'sqdOP yWX7d     _8A5w5    ')]")
```

**Try 5** (CSS)

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".sqdOP .yWX7d     ._8A5w5    ")
```

In the end add

```
your_button.click()
```

Comment: so i've tried both but it says: `NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//button[contains(@class,'sqdOP.yWX7d._8A5w5')]"}`

Comment: Please accept/upvote my answer if if is helpful

Comment: so now i have the same problem as before, it finds the element, click() doesnt throw an error but it still doesnt click it
That's my code:
https://pastebin.com/bLLmPQCs

Comment: i linked you the code, i am executing click()

Comment: OK, this means the button is clicked? What do you expect after it is clicked?

Comment: try to add time.sleep(5) before the click and check is something is changed.

Comment: that it accepts the request, it works when i click it manually

Comment: What is changed on UI side?

Comment: when it should be clicked nothing happens, i doesnt get highlighted or anything

Comment: So, your button is clicked. What is the function of this button?

Comment: the button should accept a message request

Comment: when i click the accept button manually it accepts the message request like it should, but when selenium clicks it nothing happens

Comment: Check Try 4. Try similar options by yourself

Comment: don't i have to add dots between the classes?

Comment: You can, but It will be css. I'll add it